# Using Ant library in groovy shared library for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have built a jenkins shared library to leverage for builds. I would to leverage ant because it has a lot of great utility methods for modifying files easily. However, I can't seem to get it to work in my jenkins environment.

I have a very simple ant method in the library:

```
@NonCPS
static void antReplace(String file, String token, String value){
    def ant = new AntBuilder()

    ant.replace(file: "${file}", token: "${token}", value: "${value}")
}
```

This is really weird. I do not get any errors, but the file is untouched when I call this method.

Is there any sort of special configuration to use ant in jenkins? Even to turn on error output? I just need something to debug this further. I would really like to use the library in my system.

Below is screenshot of the ant configuration in Jenkins.

[image: Jekins Ant configuraiton]

I feel like I have a very simple use case for the example. All the parameters are fine. The really stumping part is that there is no feedback to debug.

To add some context, I am using a Jenkinsfile, multi-branch pipeline build job using declarative pipeline sync. A global var function from the library is triggered from the jenkinsfile which calls this method from a src util class of the library.

Global Var:

```
import groovy.transform.Field
import org.utilities.Utils

@Field
Utils utils = new Utils()

def call() {
    utils.antReplace("${env.WORKSPACE}\\myfile.sql", "xxxDBNAMExxx",  "mydbname")
    utils.antReplace("${env.WORKSPACE}\\myfile.sql", "xxxSCHEMAxxx", "myschemaname")
}
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('jenkins_lib')_
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("test1"){
      steps{
        myGlobalVar()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Utils:

```
package org.utilities

@NonCPS
static void antReplace(String file, String token, String value){
    def ant = new AntBuilder()

    ant.replace(file: "${file}", token: "${token}", value: "${value}")
}
```

- One thing that I can also validate is that if I change `file` parameter to `ant.replace` function to `filed` I do get a groovy exception stating that's not a real parameter basically. So it is definitely calling ant.
- Another thing is that if i changed the file name I also get a problem. So it is making me think that maybe it is just not finding my tokens to replace. Not sure how ant works here. Maybe its file encoding?

Comment: Writing `"${x}"` is the same as writing just `x` (or `x?.toString()` to be accurate)

Comment: So I opened up the file in notepad++ and it was in some weird encoding so I switched it to UTF-8 and then it found the tokens to replace.

Comment: Doing something like this will most likely not do what you are expecting for a few reasons. 1) `AntBuilder` is not `Serializable`, so any pauses will crash the pipeline. 2) `AntBuilder` will be running on `master` node of Jenkins, when any step calls will be executing on remote nodes where the code actually is. 3) If this is not a global shared library, you are going to hit security and whitelist constraints.